# How can i solve this Crystal reports error?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, registry, runtime-error

I have just completed developing my web application. I was trying to deploy it to test it. When i was doing that It first gave me crystal reports related assemblies missing error then I took all Cr assemblies from my GAC to the bin, republished and redeployed my application @ someee.com

Now that error was gone but then It started giving me the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime.
>
> Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly.
>
> Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information.

All the other pages in my web app are opening perfectly but there is only one page which throws the above mentioned error. That is when the user clicks 'generate report' button on one page. This button actually loads the report and shows it in the Crystal report viewer on the same page. It works perfectly on my local server.

My application uses 2008 R2 DB server(also deployed on somee.com) , CR assemblies version = 10.5.3700.0 and it is an ASP.net web application @ 3.5 .Net framework.

I know that if I will install a CR run time package then the error will go but i cannot take that option as I don't have a remote desktop connection to my web server because it's free one. (www.somee.com)

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Have you actually installed the Crystal Reports runtime on the server (like the error message suggests) - simply copying from the GAC will **not** work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually install the CR runtime on the server as suggested because there are native libraries and registry keys to be set on the server apart from the .net dlls.

Not all hosting sites support CR so you need to find some other hosting provider that also offers CR.

Comment: Thanks for the response Cosmin. Yes, you are right. The web support team of go-daddy.com also said the same thing. They said that I should purchase a VDS and then do Rmt Des. to set it up. But then I was wondering why not host the application from my office itself? I have a static IP. What else do I need to make my local server accessible on the Internet? I know I need a domain name but I am new to hosting so I don't know how to go about it. How will I link my static WAN IP to the domain. Right now when I type my WAN IP on the net , my ISP shows up a site blocked page. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is also my problem..  and as i search .. i found this solution

1) Go to the C\inetpub\wwwroot folder on any machine that has either/or crystal report runtime engine installations. For my purposes, I just went to the one on the 2008 server I'm installing on.

2) Copy the aspnet_client folder in the wwwroot directory.

3) Paste this folder in the website directory folder. I assume this would work with a web application that was created from a virtual directory as well, just paste it into the virtual directory.

You may be able to avoid this by creating all of the necessary folders and sub folders, then copying over each file into your web application project on your development machine, in order to include them in your published, complied web application. If this is confusing, just perform the steps above in the deployment environment.

Credits to jasonHall of code project

hope it works for you